# How to replicate observations as a function of the values of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I want to replicate observations based on the values of the variable `iptw` to create pseudo-populations for further analysis.

For example, if `iptw=4.5`, then `weight=5` should be created, and the observation/row multiplied by 5. Likewise, if `iptw=2.3`, then `weight=2`, and that row is multiplied by 2, which is equivalent to adding the corresponding observation twice to the data frame.

**Here is my dataset:**

```
dtNEW <- data.table(id = 1:4, x1 = 10:13, x2=21:24, iptw=c(2.3,0.6,4.5,0.1))
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40902512) but the solutions there do not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to replicate the ith row round(iptw[i]) times:

```
dtNEW[rep(1:.N, round(iptw)), ]
```

giving:

```
   id x1 x2 iptw
1:  1 10 21  2.3
2:  1 10 21  2.3
3:  2 11 22  0.6
4:  3 12 23  4.5
5:  3 12 23  4.5
6:  3 12 23  4.5
7:  3 12 23  4.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much @G. Grothendieck. That solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `uncount` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
uncount(dtNEW, round(iptw))
#    id x1 x2 iptw
#1:  1 10 21  2.3
#2:  1 10 21  2.3
#3:  2 11 22  0.6
#4:  3 12 23  4.5
#5:  3 12 23  4.5
#6:  3 12 23  4.5
#7:  3 12 23  4.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun. This solution is great.